# Does Glassfish or applications require a restart after deploying a shared library?

Tags: maven, deployment, shared-libraries, glassfish-4

If I have a glassfish application that depends on a shared library that is running, I deploy the shared library again with updates, do I have to restart the application that depends on that shared library or will the application pick it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that answers my question.

http://alexismp.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/more-with-deploy-libraries-in-glassfish/

It makes sense that you have to restart the server or redeploy the application with the --libraries option in order for the class loader to execute to pick it up the new changes.